# Got NullPointerException when applying DOM Technique in XML Parser

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I ran this program and it reported NullPointerException at this line

```
NodeList nodeList = root.getChildNodes();
```

Here is the whole thing:

```
    package com.example.dom_technique;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class DOM extends Activity {

    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle x) {
        super.onCreate(x);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dom);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    readXML();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private void readXML() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        String output = "";

        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.student);
        Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);

        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nodeList = root.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            if (node instanceof Element) {
                Element student = (Element) node;
                String name = student.getAttribute("name");
                String student_id = student.getAttribute("student_id");

                NodeList subNodeList = student.getElementsByTagName("school");  
                String school = subNodeList.item(0).getTextContent();

                subNodeList = student.getElementsByTagName("major");
                String major = subNodeList.item(0).getTextContent();

                output += name + "  " + student_id + "\n" + school + "\n" + major +"\n" + "     ***********" + "\n";
            }
        }
        textView.setText(output);
    }

}
```

And XML file I wrote by myself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><students>

<student name="Henry Thompson" student_id="63827614">

    <school>University of California, Berkeley</school>
    <major>Computer Science</major>

</student>

<student name="Sheila Lopez" student_id="02817281">

    <school>University of California, Los Angeles</school>
    <major>Electrical Engineering</major>

</student>

<student name="Gabriel Carter" student_id="92717290">

    <school>University of California, Davis</school>
    <major>Mathematics</major>

</student>

<student name="Stephanie Nguyen" student_id="83729337">

    <school>University of California, San Diego</school>
    <major>Business Administraion, Concentration in Marketing</major>

</student>

</students>
```

Barely can I understand why, I thought I went through every requirements. I suspect the problem may come from the XML file. At first, I tried to create a XML file in drawable folder and it reported bug. Therefore I wrote in notepad, saved with xml extension and imported into drawable, then it was fine.
Please help me!!! Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: where is the stacktrace ? did you put a break point and debug?

Comment: No, I did not put break point. The Log Cat showed me that I got NullPointerException

Comment: well do that first and if you want help post stacktrace

Comment: Sorry but I think I already mentioned the stacktrace right in the title of my  question, I mentioned it in question again and again I mentioned it in the comment above yours.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your xml is missing the closing `</students>` tag in the end. So the root element (which is "students") cannot be parsed correctly.

The opening "students" tag is a bit hidden in the first line.

Comment: Oh ya, you are right, but it was my fault typing. I had it in my orignal program. Let me fix!!!

Comment: root is obviously null. That means that the Document "doc" is probably an empty document. So my guess would be that the resource you are opening is in some way not correct, possibly empty.

Comment: I do not know that using parse(InputStream) is okay in this situation, most tutorial use file from SD card, I used Internal Storage. It has parse(Input Stream) but I am just afraid it is not appropriate in this situation. Do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

For those who took your time to consider my problem, I want to express my gratitude towards everyone
Fortunately, I figured out how to fix mine, which is renaming student.xml into student only. It seems like everything we import into drawable, if we want it to work, we should not mention extension. I tried, it worked perfectly.
Once time again, thank you so much!!!!